# Excel crashes when copying columns with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro that opens an Excel file (**.xlsx**) with 6300 rows and 73 columns (the rows number is not always the same because this file is a report) and copies some columns (choosen by the user and stored in an array called *stringArray*) in the second sheet of the current **.xlsm** workbook (the workbook where I'm running the macro).
The code works almost as expected if I make an assegnment using **.Value** but without the column formatting of the source file (colored columns and borders).

If I use the **.copy** method without **.Value** Excel locks and I have to terminate it from task manager.

**stringArray** is an array populated with the content of a cell and contains "D, E, G, F, K, L, M, Q, R, S, U, V, W, X, Z, AD, AE, AF, AH, AJ, AK, AL, AM, AW, AX"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

SOLVED:
the problem was a useless declaration of a new excel instance:  `Dim app As New Excel.Application`

```
Dim SrcColsRange As String
Dim DestColsRange As String
Dim Col_char1 As String
Dim app As New Excel.Application

app.Visible = False

Set srcWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open(FileNameSrc)

L = LBound(stringArray)
U = UBound(stringArray)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells.Clear

For x = L To U
    ''''''''' Col_Letter RETURNS THE COLUMN LETTER FROM 1 (x+1) TO n (NUMBER OF COLUMNS PRESENT IN stringArray)
    Col_char1 = Col_Letter(x + 1)
    SrcColsRange = stringArray(x) & ":" & stringArray(x)
    DestColsRange = Col_char1 & ":" & Col_char1
    
    ''''''''' IT WORKS BUT WITHOUT SOURCE FILE FORMATTING '''''''''
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range(DestColsRange).Value = srcWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(SrcColsRange).Value
    
    ''''''''' IT DOESN'T WORK AND LOCKS EXCEL '''''''''
    srcWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(SrcColsRange).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range(DestColsRange)
    
Next x

srcWorkbook.Close
MsgBox "File imported successfully!", vbInformation, "Finito!"
```

Comment: Is the code within Excel?  You use `app As New Excel.Application` so thinking it could be another application.  Also, what is `stringArray`?  Are you using [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement) - `srcWorkbook` doesn't have have a Dim statement (_Tools ~ Options ~ Require Variable Declaration_ to turn on for any new modules)

Comment: Must be in Excel as you use `ThisWorkbook`.  Not sure why you're creating a new instance of Excel then.

Comment: It behaves as you describe because of the fact that Excel exceeds the allocated memory. 1. Copying the whole column consumes a lot of memory. You need to determine the last column row and copy only that range. Anyhow, using clipboard for large ranges takes time. 2.  You should use the working variant (for the range having data), followed by `.Copy` and in the next code line use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range(DestColsRange).Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats`. 3. I suppoose that `stringArray` contains columns to be copied. Please, edit your question and show us what it contains.

Comment: I am asking about that `stringArray` to see if not a much faster solution cannot be implemented. Then, why do you use a new session for what you try doing? Only to load the memory with its "contribution"?

Comment: We asked about the meaning of this code line `Dim app As New Excel.Application`. Is there an unknown reason, except loading memory unjustified? Please, try explaining this issue. I would like to place an answer but I am afraid that I'm maybe missing something...

Comment: Dim app As New Excel.Application is a mistake... and this error was the problem

Comment: OK, I will prepare an answer...

Comment: Please, test the code I pasted and send some feedback. It should be faster then yours, even working in the same session...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code. It uses arrays to rapidly copy values and `Application.Index` function which is able to extract specific columns of the array (in a different order, if necessary...).

Then, it copies format, which takes longer, but it shouldn't kill Excel:

```
Sub ImportData()
 Dim FileNameSrc As String, SrcColsRange As String, lastRow As Long, arr, arrColNo, arrFin, x As Long
 Dim srcWorkbook As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, rngCopy As Range, stringArray
 Const strCols As String = "D, E, G, F, K, L, M, Q, R, S, U, V, W, X, Z, AD, AE, AF, AH, AJ, AK, AL, AM, AW, AX"
 
 stringArray = Split(strCols, ", ")
 
 FileNameSrc = "your Workbook to import from full name" 'Please, use here the real full name!
 Set srcWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileNameSrc)
 Set wsSrc = srcWorkbook.Sheets(1)
 lastRow = wsSrc.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'last row of the larger column
 
 Set rngCopy = wsSrc.Range("A1:" & stringArray(UBound(stringArray)) & lastRow) 'set the range to be processed
 arr = rngCopy.Value   'place the range to be processed in an array

 arrColNo = getArrColsNo(strCols, ", ") 'load an array of necessary columns to be returned NUMBERS
 
 arrFin = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arr) & ")"), arrColNo) ' The necessary final array!

 Set wsDest = wsSrc.Next     ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2) 'set the destination sheet
 wsDest.cells.ClearContents  'clear the destination sheet contents
 
 'drop the final array content, at once and AutoFit the dropped columns:
 With wsDest.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2))
    .Value = arrFin
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
 End With
 
 'copy each column format (this part will take some time...):
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  For x = 0 To UBound(arrColNo)
    rngCopy.Columns(arrColNo(x)).Copy
    wsDest.cells(1, x + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats 'paste only the format of the copied column
  Next x
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 
 wsDest.Activate 'activate the destination sheet...

 srcWorkbook.Close
 MsgBox "File imported successfully!", vbInformation, "Finito!"
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.